# Erase logical volume and use freed space to enlarge existing volume on RAID

Tags: command-line, partitioning, raid, headless

I am working remotely in command line and need to remove old unused volume and use this freed space to enlarge the volume holding /home.

- I am not sure of the terminology so see relevant lsblk below.
- Take note there is 6 physical drive, so this tree repeats for `sda`,`sdb`,`sdc`,`sdd`,`sde` and `sdf`
- v0-portage is empty and unused
- v0-opt has been moved to the same drive as root (and is empty anyway)
- v0-backup has been moved to another machine and is unsued and empty.

Using the command line wish to remove `v0-portage`, `v0-opt` and `v0-backup` and reuse the space to grow `v0-home`.

```
sda                8:0    0  3.7T  0 disk  
└─sda1             8:1    0  3.7T  0 part  
  └─md0            9:0    0 14.6T  0 raid6 
    ├─v0-home    253:1    0    3T  0 lvm   /home
    ├─v0-portage 253:2    0  500G  0 lvm   
    ├─v0-opt     253:3    0  1.5T  0 lvm   
    └─v0-backup  253:4    0    3T  0 lvm   

sdb                8:16   0  3.7T  0 disk 
  .. same as sda
sdc                8:32   0  3.7T  0 disk  
  .. same as sda
sdd                8:48   0  3.7T  0 disk  
  .. same as sda
sde                8:64   0  3.7T  0 disk  
  .. same as sda
sdf                8:80   0  3.7T  0 disk  
  .. same as sda
```

From my understandin, `v0-` are `logical volume` ... that reside on a raid partition `md0` ... that are on physical volumes `sda` .. `sdf`. Is that correct? it would help for further research if i have the right terms.

I have manafed partition often using the installer and gparted but since i'm romtely away i don't want to mess this up in the command line. I imagine the procedure would look something like:

1. umount unused lv (already unmounted)
2. delete unused lv with `lvremove` ?
3. use `xfs_growfs` to grow v0-home (since it's xfs and not ext3/4)

I have found many tutorail on adding, removing or creating RAID storage but nothing about this particular case. Is that possible (surely), and what command i need to use. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing a step and made me unsure but here how's:

1. unmount the volume to be deleted

   ```
   umount /mnt/portage
   umount /mnt/backup
   ...
   ```
2. remove the lvm, to list them first use `lvdisplay`

   ```
   lvremove /dev/v0/portage
   lvremove /dev/v0/backup
   ...
   ```

   https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/lvremove.8.html
3. extend the lvm to grow (the step i was missing)

   ```
   lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/v0/home
   ```

   https://access.redhat.com/solutions/44089
4. grow the filesystem, xfs in my case

   ```
   xfs_growfs -d /dev/v0/home  #for xfs
   #resize2fs /dev/v0/home     #for ext3/ext4
   ```

   https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man8/xfs_growfs.8.html
5. Adjust /etc/fstab accordinly.
   5.1 edit `/etc/fstab`
   5.2 remove (or comment) deleted volume entries.
   5.3 save and quit.

Comment: i will use this as accepted answer in 2 days since it worked.